# Responsive Card Menu Content Overflow

Tags: html, css, user-interface, responsive-design

Its required to create a mobile responsive card menu like this using HTML & CSS:

**

- Requirement

**
[required design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG8X9.png)

But the outcome was like the below. The text are going all over,cards aren't centered,and changes the position from device to device:

[actual outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBL8W.pnges)

**

- My coding

**

```css
 <section id="edu-coursecategory-section" class="ed-coursecategory layout-2">
 

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Float four columns side by side */
.columncat {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the counter cards */
.cardcat {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 50%;
 font-size: 50%;
}
  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
.ed-coursecategory layout-2 , .isotop-active, .ed-courses layout-2{
       display:box;
   }
   
   .columncat{
      display:none ;
     
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 781px) {
 
.ed-coursecategory layout-2,  .isotop-active, .ed-courses layout-2{
       display:none;
   }
   
   .columncat{
    width: auto;
    display: box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="columncat">
    <div class="cardcat">
      <h3>Technology</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columncat">
    <div class="cardcat">
      <h3>Science</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="columncat">
    <div class="cardcat">
      <h3>Math</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="columncat">
    <div class="cardcat">
      <h3>Health & Lifestyle</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columncat">
    <div class="cardcat">
      <h3>Language</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Appreciate if you could support me to achieve the required design.

Comment: You might consider using [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) instead of `float` & `display: table`. You'll get a much more predictable result.

Comment: Hello @bryce thanks for your support.It helped a lot. 
But theres a small issue.
The menus are horizontal (correct) when checking the mobile view from my laptop,but when actually checking from mobile its seen vertical.(which is wrong).
FYI:I refered this example too:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-area_named2
How can you help me in this regard?

Comment: Is the issue you're having with new code you've created after posting this question? If so I'd ask another question about that instead of trying to get it solved here. That keeps answers consistent when people search SO for solutions later on.

Comment: Noted with thanks @bryce